# Adding an else to a condition

Tags: php

I have code here from a wordpress theme that I'm trying to change to show male/female default avatar. I have this so far, which works fine but I'm not sure how to add an else condition, I've been trying for a few hours with no luck.

Here is my code for male.

```
    if (isset($default[0]) && $gender == 'man') {
        $imagemale = themex_resize($default[0], $size, $size, true, true); 
    }
    return  '<img src="' . $imagemale . '" class="avatar" width="' . $size . '" alt="' . $alt . '" />';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: how do you get your image reference? it is in $default[0] ?

Comment: What do you want to check if the gender is male or female? You should format your code when posting, this is hard to read as is.

Comment: So what have you tried? Control structures are fundamentally simple, but without providing your attempt we can't help you to fix your code!

Comment: Robbie, I;ve tried if(isset($default[0]) && $gender == 'man') {
   $image=themex_resize($default[0], $size, $size, true, true); 

                                          return  '<img src="'.$imagemale.'" class="avatar" width="'.$size.'" alt="'.$alt.'" />'; 

                            }else if(isset($default[0]) && $gender == 'woman') {
                $image=themex_resize($default[0], $size, $size, true, true);  

                                          return  '<img src="'.$imagefemale.'" class="avatar" width="'.$size.'" alt="'.$alt.'" />'; 
          } but it does not show any avatars

Comment: @Nick please add your attempt (formatted correctly) to the question, not in a comment. At a quick glance, the "woman" if statement is setting `$image` but referencing `$imagefemale`, and the "male" is doing the same thing e.g. setting `$image` and referencing `$imagemale`

Answer (score 1):

The code that worked in the end was...

```
public static function getAvatar($avatar, $user, $size, $default, $alt) {
    if(isset($user->user_id)) {
        $user=$user->user_id;
    }

    $avatar_id=ThemexCore::getUserMeta($user, 'avatar');
    $default=wp_get_attachment_image_src( $avatar_id, 'preview');
                        if(ThemexCore::getUserMeta($user, 'gender')=='woman') {
              $image=THEME_URI.'images/default-female.jpg';
                        } else {
              $image=THEME_URI.'images/default-male.jpg';
                        }

    if(isset($default[0])) {
        $image=themex_resize($default[0], $size, $size, true, true);
    }

    return '<img src="'.$image.'" class="avatar" width="'.$size.'" alt="'.$alt.'" />';
}
```

This solution came from the script author. Thanks for trying to help CoderCreative.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $default is a set of default avatar images (0 being male, and 1 being female), you'll want something like this:

```
$tag = '';
$key = $gender=='man' ? 0 : 1;

if (isset($default[$key])) {
    $image = themex_resize($default[$key], $size, $size, true, true); 
    $tag = '<img src="'.$image.'" class="avatar" width="'.$size.'" alt="'.$alt.'" />';
}

return $tag;
```

Of course, if there are more choices for gender, or if there is a default fallback, this can be improved upon further.

**EDIT**

According to your link in the comments below, the full function is as follows:

```
public static function getAvatar($avatar, $user, $size, $default, $alt) {

    if(isset($user->user_id)) {
        $user=$user->user_id;
    }

    $gender=ThemexCore::getUserMeta($user, 'gender');
    $avatar_id=ThemexCore::getUserMeta($user, 'avatar');
    $default=wp_get_attachment_image_src( $avatar_id, 'preview');                            
    $imagemale=THEME_URI.'images/default-male.jpg';
    $imagefemale=THEME_URI.'images/default-female.jpg';

    if(isset($default[0]) && $gender == 'man') {
        $imagemale=themex_resize($default[0], $size, $size, true, true);  
        $result='<img src="'.$imagemale.'" class="avatar" width="'.$size.'" alt="'.$alt.'" />'; 
    }else if(isset($default[0]) && $gender == 'woman') {
        $imagefemale=themex_resize($default[0], $size, $size, true, true); 
        $result='<img src="'.$imagefemale.'" class="avatar" width="'.$size.'" alt="'.$alt.'" />';
    }

    return $result;

}
```

This is more complicated than simply adding in an else statement. Try this:

```
public static function getAvatar($avatar, $user, $size, $default, $alt) {

    if(isset($user->user_id)) {
        $user=$user->user_id;
    }

    $avatar_id=ThemexCore::getUserMeta($user, 'avatar');
    $unique=wp_get_attachment_image_src( $avatar_id, 'preview');

    if(isset($unique[0])) {
        $url = $unique[0];
    } else {
        $gender=ThemexCore::getUserMeta($user, 'gender');
        if($gender == 'man') {
            $url = THEME_URI.'images/default-male.jpg';
        } elseif($gender == 'woman') {
            $url = THEME_URI.'images/default-female.jpg';
        } 
    }

    $image=themex_resize($url, $size, $size, true, true);  
    return '<img src="'.$image.'" class="avatar" width="'.$size.'" alt="'.$alt.'" />'; 

}
```

Note; If the user has an avatar already the function will return that one (if a female user has a male avatar; you will see a male avatar), if no existing avatar is found for the user the function will now default to a gender-specific one as specified by you. Also note that the defaults are now hard-coded into your function, so the `$default` parameter is no longer used.

Comment: CoderCreative, Gender is stored as 'woman' and 'man' in the database.

Comment: What is in $default? if there's only one array element (at index 0) then you probably only have one default avatar available; the male one. Check by writing the following code before the "return" line; print_r($default);exit;

Comment: default is $default=wp_get_attachment_image_src( $avatar_id, 'preview');

Comment: [link](http://www.miletracker.ca/code.txt) that is my code, I added a link because I dont have room to put it here. You can see what I want to do but still no luck. thanks.

Comment: CoderCreative, that doesn't work, if you pick an avatar t will show, other then that nothing shows.

Comment: Check the image tag is being outputted to the page, and look at what is being applied to the `src` attribute. It's possible that your function might not be getting called when a user has no avatar to get, or that the hard-coded default image URLs are incorrect or incompatible with the `themex_resize()` function. Also, it's worth noting that in your original code, although the default URLs were assigned to variables, they were never used; they got overwritten every time. I'd be surprised if your original code provided any image tag at all when the user had no pre-existing avatar, even for men.